# Issue with Array and foreach

Tags: php

Hi I have this array called $allextensionsforque. See print_r below.

```
Array ( [0] => Local/101@from-queue/n,0 [data] => Local/101@from-queue/n,0 )
```

I'm trying a foreach like below but its not showing any data on the echo. Can anyone help?

```
$allextensionsforqueu = mysqli_query($conqueue,"SELECT data FROM queues_details WHERE id = '1'     AND keyword ='member'");
$allextensionsforque = mysqli_fetch_array($allextensionsforqueu);

$foo = "";
foreach ($allextensionsforque as $extensionrow) 
{
$extensionrowstriped = substr($extensionrow['data'],6,3);
$foo = "' " . $extensionrowstriped . " ' ,";
}
echo $foo;
```

Comment: note how your array has both a numbered and a named index. This is not a normal array, and looks like the output of an impropertly filtered database request. The way it's now, you probably want to iterate over `keys(arr)` and ignore anything that is a number, OR properly filter the result, so you either get a numbered index, or only the named indices: http://ca3.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array - don't rely on `MYSQLI_BOTH`

Comment: inside the foreach loop on the first run $extensionrow =$allextensionsforque[0] and the 2nd $allextensionsforque[data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an array in $extensionrow, since it's only an one dimensional array. So you just need to replace `$extensionrowstriped = substr($extensionrow['data'],6,3);` with `$extensionrowstriped = substr($extensionrow,6,3);`.

Comment: Thanks Charlotte, that saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Hi, I only though this worked, as there is an problem with the Array. My SQL query returns : Local/101@from-queue/n,0 & Local/102@from-queue/n,0. But as you can see in the Array above Local/101@from-queue/n,0 is in twice and as Mike said that the array is not normal. Would you know why the array does not include Local/102@from-queue/n,0?

Answer (score -1):

Check for errors using mysqli_error(). Here is a simple approach, but you may want to improve it for production use:

```
$allextensionsforqueu = mysqli_query($conqueue,"...") or die(mysqli_error($conqueue));
```

Next, append your data to `$foo` instead of overwritting it in each loop:

```
$foo .= "' " . $extensionrowstriped . " ' ,";
```

Finally, verify that `$extensionrow` contains the data that you expect. `substr()` will return false if a match is not found.